# nginx rewrite move from risky if statements to try_files. Can anybody help convert? (short)

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am trying to clean up my nginx rewrite rules for my vBulletin forum which has some modifications and additional software within the same site which causes problems. I have things working as they should, but according to [nginx If is Evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) I am concerned and would like to try and convert these few rules into try_files instead.

Currently, there is

1. A rule for static images and files so they do not get passed to the seo mod (e.g. .gif,.ico, even .css)
2. A rule for the subfolder mobiquo which is aka: tapatalk plugin. In order for that to work, I had to exclude the whole directory from rewrites.
3. If the file does not exist. I'm not sure how important that is, but it seems like a good idea. Maybe it's to lower the work of the seo mod.

The nginx rewrite rules in the apparently risky If block form:

### this is above the /forum/ block because I wanted to give it priority, if this is improperly done I would love to know.

```
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
            # Some basic cache-control for static files to be sent to the browser
            expires max;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    location /forum/ {

            try_files $uri $uri/ /forum/dbseo.php?$args;

            if ($request_uri ~* ^/forum/mobiquo) {
                    break;
            }

            if (-f $request_filename) {
            expires 30d;
                    break;
            }

            if ($request_filename ~ "\.php$" ) {
                    rewrite ^(/forum/.*)$ /forum/dbseo.php last;
            }


            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^/forum/(.*)$ /forum/dbseo.php last;
            }

    }
```

END

Somewhere in my searches I found a template which I tried to adapt, but since I'm not understanding regex's I failed :)

## location / {

```
            # if you're just using wordpress and don't want extra rewrites
            # then replace the word @rewrites with /index.php
```

## try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

## }

## location @rewrites {

```
            # Can put some of your own rewrite rules in here
            # for example rewrite ^/~(.*)/(.*)/? /users/$1/$2 last;
            # If nothing matches we'll just send it to /index.php
```

## try_files $uri $uri/ /forum/dbseo.php?$args;

## rewrite ^ /index.php last;

## rewrite ^(/.php)$ /forum/dbseo.php last;

## }

Comment: I guess your issue with the mod dbseo not the block itself!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to cleanse you question, especially the end of it shere you are shouting instead of providing code.

Based on the configuration you provided at the top of you question, I ended up with that:

```
location /forum/ {
    index dbseo.php; # You obviously wish to send everything erroneous/inexistent to dbseo.php, any index.php file would suffer the regex location below
    try_files $uri $uri/ /forum/dbseo.php?$args; # Any inexistent file/directory will be handled over to /forum/dbseo.php

    location ^~ /forum/dbseo.php { # Avoids matching the regex location below (performance)
    }

    location ^~ /forum/mobiquo { # Avoids matching any other rules
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files /forum/dbseo.php =404;
        # Be careful here, try to secure your location since the regex can still be manipulated for arbitrary code execution
    }
}
```

Nested locations are a good thing for isolation of potentially conflicting location blocks. Keep in mind that regex locations are evaluated seuqentially, thus to avoid the location blocks order having an impact (which is a mess just like Apache configuration), try to always enclose regex locations in prefix ones to avoid several of them following each other.

You can learn about [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) modifiers on its documentation page.

Maybe are there more subtelties, but you have all the basic information you need in my example. THe job is yours to understand/improve it to better suit your needs. :o)